# How to avoid INJECT_EVENTS Security Exception in automated Android testing?

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium

Is there any chance to take a snapshot from Android native camera from your own app, and avoid INJECT_EVENTS Security Exception.

Advise something, please.

P.S I use Robotium and failed to do that

Comment: advice: don't use robotium to do that

Comment: Terrific! Can you be more specific, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Robotium is based on instrumentation which was designed to test just one activity, if I'm not wrong. Robotium is just a wrapper for instrumentation itself and provides a lot of useful methods. The issue is that instrumentation is bind strictly to target application and you cannot invoke anything for another context. Basically writing, if you leave your target application - press back, open another application like camera you are out of the target context and you cannot do anything. Sending any mouse events ends up with security exceptions etc.

There are other frameworks designed for cross application testing.

- First of all there is monkey runner, which uses jython (everything the worst from python and java put together). The issue is that MR allows you to just click XY and it doesn't know about screen size, so those cannot be scalable. Another issue is that clicks and drags are almost everything what MR offers. More you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)
- Second one is UIAutomator. It's quite powerful and well designed, however it supports api level 16 and above. More details [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html).
- There is also appium, which I heard allows to cross apps testing, however I don't have enough knowledge about it, so help yourself and go to [appium.io](http://appium.io/)

Anyway I suggest to read a bit more about [android testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html). Maybe [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/rIHf6ggZdRs) is going to be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hope, that some of these tools will help me.